# overlaying measured data by contours of modelled data in Healpy

Tags: python, healpy

I have some measured data: Earth's trapped charged particles such as Van Allen Belts and South Atlantic Anomaly; and modelled data: AE8/AP8 or AE9/AP9.
I would like to plot everything into one Healpy map to compare measured data and modelled data in one image. So one way could be to make a black-and-white map from measured data and then make overlying contours of modelled data, one contour for protons, the other for electrons.

EDIT2:
I found some defined plotting functions like contours and also and other stuff as well at this [GitHub](https://github.com/lscsoft/lalsuite-archive/blob/master/lalinference/python/lalinference/plot/healpix.py), specifically for Healpix. They worked well for me!

So in the code, I made a logarithmic map of modelled data "log_mymap_mod" the same way as I did for measured data "log_mymap" (in EDIT1). Then I used those functions from [GitHub](https://github.com/lscsoft/lalsuite-archive/blob/master/lalinference/python/lalinference/plot/healpix.py). And then I called it this way:

```
MyMap = hp.newvisufunc.projview(log_mymap,                                
                                title='map_and_contour', 
                                coord=["G"], 
                                graticule=True,
                                graticule_labels=True,
                                flip='geo',
                                cmap=cmap_custom,
                                projection_type = 'hammer',
                                phi_convention="symmetrical",
                                cbar=False,
                                hold=True,
                                alpha=0.3
                               )

healpix_contour(log_mymap_mod, levels=3, colors='firebrick', alpha=1.0, linewidths=1.0)

plt.show()
```

EDIT1:
this is what I tried:

so for measured data, I have longitude (from 0 to 360), latitude and count per second. Then I did some logarithmic map for which I transformed longitude to go from -180 to 180. Then I have data from the model, which are marked with '_mod'. Longitude goes from 0 to 360, so I tried to do the same thing as I did with measured data and then I somehow tried more ways to plot them as contours on my measured map but nothing worked for me.

```
lonAll2 = np.zeros_like(lonAll)

for i in range(len(lonAll)):
    if lonAll[i] >= 180.0:
        lonAll2[i] = lonAll[i] - 360.0
    else:
        lonAll2[i] = lonAll[i]

theta = (90.0 - latAll) * (np.pi / 180.0) 
phi = lonAll2 * (np.pi / 180.0)  

k = 4
nside = 2 ** k

npix = hp.nside2npix(nside)
healpix_sum = np.zeros(npix)
healpix_count = np.zeros(npix)

for i in range(len(lonAll)):
    lon = lonAll2[i]
    lat = latAll[i]
    pixel_idx = hp.ang2pix(nside, np.radians(90 - lat), np.radians(lon))
    count_rate = rateAll[i]
    
    healpix_sum[pixel_idx] += count_rate
    if count_rate > 0:
        healpix_count[pixel_idx] += 1

mask = healpix_count > 0
healpix_mean = np.where(mask, healpix_sum / healpix_count, 0)

log_mymap = np.log10(healpix_mean)

data_mod=['a.txt']
    
lonAll_mod = np.array([])
latAll_mod = np.array([])
rateAll_mod = np.array([])

for filename_mod in data_mod:
    if exists(filename_mod):
        df = pd.read_table(filename_mod, sep=',', skiprows=14)
        
        lonAll_mod = np.concatenate((lonAll_mod, df['lon(deg)'].values))
        latAll_mod = np.concatenate((latAll_mod, df['lat(deg)'].values))
        rateAll_mod = np.concatenate((rateAll_mod, df['flux'].values))

    else:
        print("File not found:", filename_mod)

cmap_custom2 = plt.cm.get_cmap('Greys')

MyMap = hp.newvisufunc.projview(log_mymap,
                                title='VZLU_rch2_k4_mean_geq0_contour', 
                                coord=["G"], 
                                graticule=True,
                                graticule_labels=True,
                                flip='geo',
                                cmap=cmap_custom2,
                                projection_type = 'hammer',
                                phi_convention="symmetrical",
                                cbar=False
                               )

ax = plt.gca()

lonAll_mod2 = np.zeros_like(lonAll_mod)
for i in range(len(lonAll_mod)):
    if lonAll_mod[i] >= 180.0:
        lonAll_mod2[i] = lonAll_mod[i] - 360.0
    else:
        lonAll_mod2[i] = lonAll_mod[i]

lon_grid, lat_grid = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-180, 180, int(np.sqrt(rateAll_mod.size))), 
                                 np.linspace(-90, 90, int(np.sqrt(rateAll_mod.size))))

rateAll_mod_grid = griddata((lonAll_mod2, latAll_mod), rateAll_mod, (lon_grid, lat_grid), method='cubic')

theta_grid, phi_grid = hp.pix2ang(nside=nside, ipix=hp.ang2pix(nside, lon_grid, lat_grid, lonlat=True), lonlat=True)

contour = ax.contour(theta_grid, phi_grid, rateAll_mod_grid, levels=5, colors='red')

plt.show()
```

Comment: have you tried to use `plt.contour` after creating a figure with `projview`? it would be useful to have a minimal example with some easy data simulated on the fly.

Comment: thank you for your reply. So I edited my question. So do you think it is possible to overlay contours of modelled data on that spherical healpy image of measured data? ... not cartesian

Comment: the example should be executable without requiring any external data, so I can paste it into a notebook and run it.

Comment: I did not know how to simulate my data and my dataset is too long. But I found some Healpix plotting functions at GitHub and they worked well! So my problem looks solved. I edited my question and I hope it is described understandably.